# IE9 issue with static content from JBoss 7.1

Tags: jboss7.x

When serving static content from JBoss 7.1 Application server, like CSS files (from folder welcome-content or its sub-folders), all browsers, except Internet Explorer (IE), can recognize with no any issues the actual type (MIME Type) of the file. Is there a specific configuration in JBoss 7.1 to achieve this/to solve IE issue, or simply we need to move the static content in a dedicated web application server, like Apache HTTPD, where we would have more control on MIME type? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is not recommended use `welcome-content` to serve you own content. If you take a look at the code of `org.jboss.as.web.WelcomeContextService`, the only mime types added are `text/html` and `image/jpeg`:

```java
public synchronized void start(StartContext startContext) throws StartException {
    HttpManagement httpManagement = httpManagementInjector.getOptionalValue();
        try {
            context.setPath("");
            context.addLifecycleListener(new ContextConfig());
            context.setDocBase(pathInjector.getValue() + File.separatorChar + "welcome-content");


            ....

            Wrapper wrapper = context.createWrapper();
            wrapper.setName("default");
            wrapper.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
            context.addChild(wrapper);

            context.addServletMapping("/", "default");
            context.addMimeMapping("html", "text/html");
            context.addMimeMapping("jpg", "image/jpeg");

            .....

            context.create();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new StartException(MESSAGES.createWelcomeContextFailed(), e);
        }
        try {
            context.start();
        } catch (LifecycleException e) {
            throw new StartException(MESSAGES.startWelcomeContextFailed(), e);
        }
}
```

If you need to access static resources in the root, you can perform the deploy their own application in the root.

1. Stop server if running
2. Set `enable-welcome-root` to false in `stanalone.xml` as only one app can run in root context.

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
    <configuration>
        <mime-mapping name="manifest" value="text/xml"/>
    </configuration>
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

3. Add `ROOT.war` folder (**Exploded war**) or Your own folder with .war as part of the name in deployments folder. The structure of `ROOT.war` is as follows:

> ```
> ROOT.war
> ROOT.war/WEB-INF
> ```

4. Add the file `ROOT.war.dodeploy` in deployments folder
5. Start the server

A alternative method is add a apache as frontend to serve static content or use a public CDN.

I hope this help